# Divide string into several substrings

Tags: java, android

I have a strings that contain only digits. String itself would look like this "0011112222111000" or "1111111000". I'd like to know how can I get an array of substrings  which will consist of strings with only one digit.
For example, if I have "00011111122233322211111111110000000"  string, I 'd like it to be in string array(`string[]`) which contains `["000","111111","222","333","222","1111111111","0000000"]`.

This is what I've tried

```
for (int i = (innerHierarchy.length()-1); i >= 1; i--) {
                                Log.e("Point_1", "innerHierarchy " + innerHierarchy.charAt(i));
                                c = Character.toChars(48 + max);
                                Log.e("Point_1", "c " + c[0]);
                                if (innerHierarchy.charAt(i) < c[0] && innerHierarchy.charAt(i - 1) == c[0]) {
                                    Log.e("Point_1", "Start " + string.charAt(i));
                                    o = i;
                                } else if (innerHierarchy.charAt(i) == c[0] && innerHierarchy.charAt(i - 1) < c[0]) {
                                    Log.e("Point_1", "End " + string.charAt(i));
                                    o1 = i;
                                    string[j] = string.substring(o1,o);
                                    j=j+1;
                                }
                            }
```

But this code won't work if string looks like this "111111000"

Thank you.

Comment: A few lines of code involving a loop will do. Try it and come back with concrete questions if you have problems. Stackoverflow is not a coding machine!

Comment: @Henry It would be interesting if there exists a regex solution.

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting this? It's a perfectly legit question.

Comment: @FieryPhoenix tooltip for the downvote button: "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: For what it's worth, I would also be interested to know if there exists a way to do this without brute-force. Like split() with regex.

Comment: @Henry I've added my code, take a look

Comment: @FieryPhoenix yeah I too agree with you that it's a very legitimate question! +1 for you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have "00011111122233322211111111110000000" string, I 'd like it to
>   be in string array(string[]) which contains
>   ["000","111111","222","333","222","1111111111","0000000"]

One approach I can think of right now (**O(n)**) *(might not be the most efficient but would solve your problem)* would be traversing the string of numbers i.e. ("00011111122233322211111111110000000"  in your case )

and if char at that position under consideration is not same as char at previous position then making string till that part as one string and continuing.

(approach)

considering str= "00011111122233322211111111110000000"

```
//starting from position 1 (ie from 2nd char which is '0')

   //which is same as prev character ( i.e 1st char which is '0') 
       // continue in traversal 
       // now char at pos 2 which is again '0'
       // keep traversing
       // but then char at position 3 is 1 
       // so stop here and
       //make substring till here-1 as one string
       //so "000" came as one string
  //continue in same manner.
```

**code**

```
   import java.util.*;

    public class A {
        public static void main(String []args){
    String str = "00011111122233322211111111110000000";
    str+='-';  //appended '-' to get last 0000000 as well into answer
                //otherwise it misses last string which i guess was your problem
    String one_element ="";
    int start=0;

    for(int i=1;i<str.length();i++){
       if(str.charAt(i)== str.charAt(i-1) )
          {

          }
       else{
          one_element = str.substring(start,i);
          start = i;
          System.out.println(one_element);//add one_element into ArrayList if required.
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

**I have printed each element here as string , if you need an array of all those you can simply use an array_list and keep adding *one_element* in array_list instead of printing.**

Comment: yeah ..sure, am trying a code that would solve your problem, and would work for 111110000 as well, give me some time!

Comment: @steve check if my recent solution  works for you, feel free for any other help. even for your test case as str= "111110000" it would work